# target_url parameter is missing on facebook deeplink for android

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

I have implemented deeplink on my app using a small php page located on my server, i am able to generate the deeplinks and share the content for whatsapp g+ and facebook. When testing those deeplinks i am automatically redirected to the application however this behavior is inconsistent on facebook.

On some links i was directed to the installed app and on some deeplinks the facebook app internal browser opened.

After some investigation i found that there is a difference between the two calls, one is having the target_url parameter as you can see below:

I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://amircar.ddns.net/amircarbe/dlk.php?pid=80&fid=541c48171e683.jpg&c=80&**target_url**=http://amircar.ddns.net/amircarbe/dlk.php?pid=80&fid=541c48171e683.jpg&c=80

and the other does not have it:

I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://amircar.ddns.net/amircarbe/dlk.php… cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.browser.lite.BrowserLiteActivity (has extras)}

I am working facebook **scraper** to check my URL and it seems to be valid.

can be tested with http://amircar.ddns.net/amircarbe/dlk.php?pid=30&fid=1150.jpg&c=30

has anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So a workaround that I found was to launch an intent from the brwoser with a fallback URL, i followed this URL https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents that give an example how to create this intent, so once you have the correct scheme in the application than it will launch automatically however if the app is not installed it will fallback to the play store

hope that helps someone